# Quadratic Residues in $\{a\}\cup\{ah^2+bh+c:0\leq h<p\}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $p\nmid b^2-4ac$ for integers $a>0,b,c$. Can we show the set
$$
\{a\}\cup\{ah^2+bh+c:0\leq h<p\}
$$
contains an equal number of quadratic residues and non-residues modulo $p$?

Comment: As @MarcBogaerts observed, this is false. But if you replace "set" by "multiset", it should be true. It then boils down to $\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right) + \sum\limits_{h=0}^{p-1} \left(\dfrac{ah^2+bh+c}{p}\right) = 0$, which I think is a known fact.

Comment: Ah, there we are: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892074/

Answer (score 1):

Contradiction: with $a = 10, b = 5, c = 3, p =97$ the set contains $50$ quadratic residues and $48$ non-residues.

Comment: I get $25$ and $24$ instead, but still a counterexample.

Comment: I forgot that the values $ah^2+bh+c$ occured twice.

Comment: $\{a\}\cup\{ah^2+bh+c:0\leq h<p\} = \{10\} \cup \{0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 29, 33, 34, 35, 37, 40, 42, 43, 44, 46, 48, 49, 50, 53, 56, 58, 63, 68, 70, 73, 76, 77, 78, 80, 82, 83, 84, 86, 89, 91, 92, 93 \}$ 
This set has 50 elements.
Among these, the QRs are the following:
$\{0, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 18, 22, 24, 25, 33, 35, 43, 44, 48, 49, 50, 53, 70, 73, 86, 89, 91, 93\}$  
The rest are QNRs. 
Hence no of QRs = no of QNRs = 25

Comment: @PTDS Indeed, you are right, I miscounted somewhere.

Comment: @PTDS QRs don't include $0$ by the usual definition. If you do include $0$, then $p = 5$, $a = 1$, $b = 0$ and $c = 1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: In this case, $\{a\}\cup\{ah^2+bh+c:0\leq h<p\} = \{0, 1, 2\}$ and the cardinality of this set
is odd. Is there any example where the cardinality of this set is even and no of QRs $\neq$ no of QNRs?

Answer (score 0):

it suffices to consider  a=1 b=0 c not 0 consider t from 1 to p-1
and consider the equation h^2+c=(h+t)^2  linear in h and hence 1 solution  further it is clear that 
now we see that 2 different t1,t2 produce the same h solution iff (h+t1)^2=(h+t2)^2  iff h+t1=-(h+t2)  or t1=-2h=t2
now choosing over all t we get that half of $\{ah^2+bh+c:1\leq h<p\}$  are squares fufilling the claim.